# How can I load jquery from Google CDN?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I don't want to create one more plugin with one more jquery lib hosted locally. I'm trying to load it from Google's CDN but I'm getting this exception:

> Refused to load the script 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".

How can I fix it?

Comment: Could you show how you are trying to load this ressource?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to load jQuery from Google's CDN you have to add the following content security rule to your manifest file.

```js
    ...
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://*.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'",
    ...
```

For more information read the official documentation Sirwan Afifi already provided and especially follow the links there to the [CSP specification](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/content-security-policy/raw-file/tip/csp-specification.dev.html#syntax) and the [article on HTML5 rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/).

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html

> **> Only local script and and object resources are loaded**
>
> > > Script and object resources can only be loaded from the extension's
> > >       package, not from the web at large. This ensures that your extension
> > >       only executes the code you've specifically approved, preventing an
> > >       active network attacker from maliciously redirecting your request for
> > >       a resource.

so, you should download jquery file and include it in your package :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Awesome Popup!</title>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button>Click for awesomeness!</button>
  </body>
</html>
```