# jQuery is undefined in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to run a simple jQuery call in a js file while making my first chrome extension but not sure why I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Here is my manifest file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Getting started example",
  "version": "1.0",

"description": "This extension shows a Google Image search result for the current page",

 "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery-2.2.0.min.js", "popup.js"],
     "persistent": false
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "Click here!"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
  ]
}
```

Here is the onclick call in popup js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  console.log("FIRE");
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "testScript.js"});
});
```

Here is the test script where the error shows:

```
console.log('foo'); 
console.log($('#page-top'));
```

foo gets printed but then I get the error on $

Comment: Try adding CDNs for jquery-2.2.0.min.js

Comment: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js

Comment: How would I include a CDN exactly?

Comment: In your `manifest` file, instead of `"scripts": ["jquery-2.2.0.min.js", "popup.js"],` make it look like `"scripts": ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js", "popup.js"],`

Comment: That does not work as can be seen on this question, and does not seem like a game changer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287806/how-to-use-jquery-from-jquery-coms-cdn-into-a-chrome-extension

Comment: Have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443001/how-can-i-load-jquery-from-google-cdn

Comment: `Could not load background script 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js'.` I am getting this error

Comment: Okay, means we can;t load throught CDN. Ok. Is your `.js` file inside `extension` folder ?

Comment: I solved it, I didn't execute the js script

Comment: LOL, Okay ! Nice it solved.

Answer (score 2):

The solution that worked for me (since I see this question asked a lot) is that it was not executed before the testScript... I changed it to this:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "jquery-2.2.0.min.js"});
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "testScript.js"});
});
```

Comment: the reason it did not work btw is because you tried to use jQuery in a content script but it was defined in a background script